# External displays connected via dock not reconnecting

Tags: ubuntu, display, docking-station, external

I have a HP laptop with Dell WD19TBS thunderbolt dock (I tried Lenovo thunderbolt dock as well with the same problem) and when I connect USB-C cable from dock to my laptop after suspend, both external displays connected to dock are not recognized. I'm on Ubuntu 22 with xwayland.

I have latest HP bios and latest dock firmware. `fwupdmgr get-updates` says 'No available updates'
I checked `dmesg` and the only error there is this one  `i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* link address NAK received` which apparently is connected to the issue, but I can't seem to find a solution.

One interesting thing is that when I disconnect and reconnect the dock (even if displays are not recognized before this disconnect) in just about the right time - not too fast, not too slow - circa 1 second - displays sometimes start to work and there is no error in `dmesg`. System restart helps always. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Latitude 7370 laptop and a HP Thunderbolt 230W G2 dock, connected to an external 4K monitor.  The distribution used is Alpine Linux with 6.6.16-lts kernel and Sway window manager (Xwayland disabled).  In the BIOS settings, I have set Thunderbolt security to `No Security`.  This is mentioned in the Arch Linux wiki for preventing authorization issues.

I encountered the exact same error. I tried upgrading the firmware of both the laptop and the dock, under Windows, to no avail.  The newer "edge" kernel also made no difference.

I have so far discovered two solutions.  One is the method you mentioned:  try repeatedly reconnect the Thunderbolt cable.  Sometimes it will work.

The other is to suspend the laptop, then wake it up, dmesg then outputs:

```
[  329.250419] drm card1-DP-3: PM: parent card1 should not be sleeping
[  329.250764] drm card1-DP-4: PM: parent card1 should not be sleeping
[  329.250946] drm card1-DP-5: PM: parent card1 should not be sleeping
[  329.251235] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[  329.251249] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[  329.251262] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:117:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
```

The last non-solution I discovered is to use [ChromeOS Flex](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/serving-builds?deviceCategory=Chrome%20OS%20Flex).  Somehow Google managed to smooth out the rough corners in their Linux distribution: plugging in the cable always result in a working external display.